# Why Fire stick main screen app behavior is different from other apps?

Tags: java, android, netflix, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-os

I observed one behavior in fire stick, apps which are present in main screen are always calling `onDestroy` on app launch, which cause app to restart and not launch where user left off.

I checked with Netflix app, even there `onDestroy` gets called on launch but they are preserving state before app close, and so able to launch from last exit state.

My doubt is, why fire stick treats main screen apps differently? I searched but did not find proper answer. Mostly people talking about is **memory getting full** which is not the case here.